# No output in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

When trying to run my java project in Eclipse, I can't see the output tab at the bottom. All I can see is Problems, JavaDoc, and Declaration. Shouldn't there be one for Output? And if so, how do I get it?

Comment: This question should be closed on grounds that it has been asked a million times, and a quick google search would have yielded an answer.

Comment: I tried to google the answer, but couldn't word the search to get me an answer.

Comment: If you are looking to restore the LogCat view (Output ?)
you can do it by the following steps:

Window-Show View-Other-LogCat

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java standard output will show in the console in eclipse. If you cannot find the view, you can show the view by the following steps:

Open Window > Show View > Console

Comment: Please don't post single-line answers. Explain the issue. -1

Comment: I prefer 1 line answers than 10 lined non-answers.

Answer (score 1):

Or else you can use the shortcut `Alt+Shift+Q` and then `C`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the Console Window may be **hiding or docked** behind the **`Package Explorer`** window (*preferrably*) or other windows. **Minimize** Package Explorer or all other windows and you will find the console window.